# How node delete pid file before restart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, pm2

I use PM2 to manage node processes, I try to delete every node's pid file, before restart, but it seems not OK everytime.

This is my code:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    fs.unlink('./log/' + process.pid);
});
```

Sometimes it works OK, sometimes some old pid file still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGTERM` may not be the only signal terminating your application. You could try something like this:

```
var signals = ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGTERM'];

signals.forEach(function (signal) {
  process.on(signal, function() {
    fs.unlink('./log/' + process.pid);
  });
});
```